# How can Solve HTTP to HTTPS issue on HTML Template

Tags: html

I have a site http://template.helloxpart.com/picasso/picasso/home_default.html, how can i secure this from http:// to https:// ?

Comment: By getting an SSL certificate.

Answer (score 1):

You need a SSL certificate. This can be provided by certain hosters or you can get one here: https://www.instantssl.com/ssl-certificate-products/https.html (paid) or here: https://letsencrypt.org/ (free).

Comment: free ad for comodo... ah ah! check [this list](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-certificate-list.html) out @user3495110

Comment: didn't know there were free certificates... edited it.